# Reverse geocoding query with Algolia places.js library

Tags: javascript, algolia

I'm using the places.js library for autocomplete, but also want to use it for reverse geocoding. According to https://community.algolia.com/places/examples.html#reverse-geocoding this should be possible - autocomplete is working fine, but not the reverse call. Code excerpt:

```
            places.configure({
                hitsPerPage: 1,
                aroundLatLng: position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude,
            });
            places.reverse({
                //aroundLatLng: position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude,
                //hitsPerPage: 1
            }).then(function(response){
                var hits = response.hits;
                var suggestion = hits[0];
                if (suggestion && (suggestion.locale_names || suggestion.city)) {
                    address_input.value = suggestion.locale_names.default[0] || suggestion.city.default[0];
                }
            });
```

This triggers a call to the correct endpoint, but errors that `aroundLatLng` is missing. I have confirmed the data is there - and also `hitsPerPage` remains at the default 5. 
As you can see from the commented lines, I've tried passing the options direct to the `reverse` call, and using `configure`.

Can anyone help tell me the correct way to use the places.js library to make a reverse call please?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure there is actual data in `position.coords.{latitude|longitude}`?

Comment: Yes 100%. There's something fundamentally wrong about what I'm doing as even the hitsPerPage value isn't passed correctly when I watch the URL called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what's wrong is how Algolia provides two ways to call reverse geocoding, but only actually documents one.

Algolia's reverse geocoding example uses the places implementation from the **algolia client** library, which allows you to do:

```js
const places = algoliasearch.initPlaces('appId', 'apiKey');
places.reverse({ aroundLatLng: 'lat,lng', hitsPerPage: 5 }).then(callback);
```

There's another `reverse` method available on the `places.js` library, and this one takes slightly different arguments:

```js
const placesAutocomplete = places({ appId: '', apiKey: '', container: inputEl });
places.reverse('lat,lng', { hitsPerPage: 5 });
```

Note how the latitude/longitude pair must be given as the first argument, and then query params as a second object argument.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks Oliver! For anyone else finding this - the response is also in a different format - just an array of results rather than needing to a access the hits object. So e.g. `var suggestion = response[0]; address_input.value = suggestion.country;` etc.